# Share git repository mappings between Visual Studio Versions

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I'm currently using VS 2015 with Git but due to features updates we're moving to VS 2017. Is there a way to share the same local copy of the code between them? Or at least a way to move the mapping from VS 2015 to VS 2017 with out needing to clone the whole code again?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not load the project using Open Project feature? Just open the project from the existing git local copy.

Comment: Because that will not allow me to change from one branch to another from VS for example or looking at the changes made in the Team View.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Share local repo between VS2015 and VS2017**. You can add the current local repo path in VS2017 Local Git Repositories.

Open Team Explorer, go to the Connect page, and in the Local Git Repositories section, click the Add button. Navigate to the repository that you cloned previously.

[image]

**Move the mapping from VS2015 to VS2017**. Firstly, add local repo path in VS2017 as above step. Then remove the local git repo in VS2015.

[image]